# Is ConcurrentDictionary.GetOrAdd() guaranteed to invoke valueFactoryMethod only once per key?

Tags: c#, .net, multithreading, parallel-processing

**Problem:** I need to implement object cache. The cache need to be thread-safe and need to populate values on demand(lazy loading). The values are retrieved via web service by Key(slow operation). So I've decided to use `ConcurrentDictionary` and its [GetOrAdd()](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee378677(v=vs.110).aspx) method that has a value factory method supposing that the operation is atomic and synchronized. Unfortunately I found the following statement in the MSDN article: [How to: Add and Remove Items from a ConcurrentDictionary](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd997369.aspx):

> Also, although all methods of ConcurrentDictionary are
>   thread-safe, not all methods are atomic, specifically GetOrAdd and
>   AddOrUpdate. The user delegate that is passed to these methods is
>   invoked outside of the dictionary's internal lock.

Well that's unfortunate but still doesn't answer my answer completely.

**Question:** Is value factory invoked only once per key? In my specific case: Is it possible that multiple threads that are looking for the same key spawning  multiple request to the web service for the same value?

Comment: No, use a CD<Key, Lazy<Value>>. That's the standard pattern.

Answer (score 40, accepted):

> Is value factory invoked only once per key?

No, it isn't. [The docs say](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee378677(v=vs.110).aspx):

> If you call `GetOrAdd` simultaneously on different threads,
>   **valueFactory may be invoked multiple times**, but its key/value pair might not be added to
>   the dictionary for every call.

Answer (score 63):

As others have already pointed out, `valueFactory` may be invoked more than once. There is a common solution that mitigates this issue - have your `valueFactory` return a `Lazy<T>` instance. Although it's possible that multiple lazy instances will be created, the actual `T` value will only be created when you access `Lazy<T>.Value` property.

Specifically:

```
// Lazy instance may be created multiple times, but only one will actually be used.
// GetObjectFromRemoteServer will not be called here.
var lazyObject = dict.GetOrAdd("key", key => new Lazy<MyObject>(() => GetObjectFromRemoteServer()));

// Only here GetObjectFromRemoteServer() will be called.
// The next calls will not go to the server
var myObject = lazyObject.Value;
```

This method is further explained in [Reed Copsey's blog post](http://reedcopsey.com/2011/01/16/concurrentdictionarytkeytvalue-used-with-lazyt/)

Comment: Sorry, my bad. I initially thought `GetOrAdd` would return the value created by `valueFactory`, so two `GetOrAdd` calls could return two different results (like the first commenter in your linked post). After a second thought, this would be totally stupid. This solution works.

Comment: Very elegant solution  +1

Comment: This approach does not guarantee that the factory method will be called once.
The fact is that Lazy<T> is created synchronously and is cheap, so it is harder for race conditions to occur, but they could still occur.

Comment: @BladeWise how so? GetOrAdd will always return value that is actually in the collection (so always the same value), then Lazy.Value will invoke the factory method only once

Comment: @Taudris The instance of `Lazy<T>` returned by `GetOrAdd` for a given key will be the same across all `GetOrAdd` invocations. Therefore the race condition cannot occur.

Parallel invocations of `GetOrAdd` which are creating new values for a given key are linearizable as follows: The first `GetOrAdd` invocation to create the value stores it in the collection. All other `GetOrAdd` invocations create their values and discard them, returning the value already stored in the collection.

Comment: So even though multiple threads can end up *creating* `Lazy<T>` instances, only one instance ever gets stored, and that's the one that all threads will return. It seems you are correct; I'll remove my comment.

Comment: Keep in mind: the exception thrown from the value factory of Lazy will be cached!

Answer (score 22):

Let's take a look at the [source code of `GetOrAdd`](http://referencesource.microsoft.com/#mscorlib/system/Collections/Concurrent/ConcurrentDictionary.cs,2f8bcdfbad10304f,references):

```
public TValue GetOrAdd(TKey key, Func<TKey, TValue> valueFactory)
{
    if (key == null) throw new ArgumentNullException("key");
    if (valueFactory == null) throw new ArgumentNullException("valueFactory");

    TValue resultingValue;
    if (TryGetValue(key, out resultingValue))
    {
        return resultingValue;
    }
    TryAddInternal(key, valueFactory(key), false, true, out resultingValue);
    return resultingValue;
}
```

Unfortunately, in this case, it's clear nothing guarantees that `valueFactory` won't be called more than once, if two `GetOrAdd` invocations happen to run in parallel.