# Can I perform an atomic try-get-or-add operation with a ConcurrentDictionary?

Tags: asp.net-core, oauth, task, openid-connect, concurrentdictionary

In my ASP.NET Core MVC web-application (that uses OIDC) I have a class that automatically refreshes the `access_token` stored in the visitor's authentication cookie before it expires.

It is based on `AutomaticTokenManagementCookieEvents` from the IdentityServer4 samples. Available here: https://github.com/IdentityServer/IdentityServer4/blob/0155beb2cea850144b6407684a2eda22e4eea3db/samples/Clients/src/MvcHybridAutomaticRefresh/AutomaticTokenManagement/AutomaticTokenManagementCookieEvents.cs

```
static readonly ConcurrentDictionary<String,Object> _pendingRefreshes = new ConcurrentDictionary<String,Object>();

public override async Task ValidatePrincipal( CookieValidatePrincipalContext context )
{
    DateTime accessTokenExpiresAt = GetAccessTokenExpiry( context ); // gets the 'expires_at' value from `context.Properties.GetTokens();`
    String refreshToken = GetRefreshToken( context ); // Gets the 'refresh_token' value from `context.Properties.GetTokens();`

    Boolean isExpired = DateTime.UtcNow > accessTokenExpiresAt;
    Boolean willExpireSoon = DateTime.UtcNow > accessTokenExpiresAt.Subtract( TimeSpan.FromSeconds( 60 ) );

    if( isExpired || willExpireSoon )
    {
        Boolean canRefresh = _pendingRefreshes.TryAdd( refreshToken, null );
        if( canRefresh )
        {
            try
            {
                await RefreshAccessTokenAsync( context, refreshToken );
            }
            finally
            {
                _pendingRefreshes.TryRemove( refreshToken );
            }
        }
        else
        {
            // TODO: What should happen here?
        }
    } 

}

private async Task RefreshAccessTokenAsync( CookieValidatePrincipalContext context, String refreshToken )
{
    // using IdentityModel.Client.HttpClientTokenRequestExtensions.RequestRefreshTokenAsync
    TokenResponse response = await this.httpClient.RefreshTokenAsync( refreshToken );
    if( response.IsError )
    {
        // (Error logging code here)

        if( response.Error == "invalid_grant" )
        {
            // Usually invalid_grant errors happen if the user's refresh_token has been revoked or expired
            // refresh_token expiry is separate from access_token expiry.
            // If a refresh_token has expired or been revoked the only thing to do is force the user to login again. `RejectPrincipal()` will send the user to the OIDC OP login page - though this will cause the user to lose their data if this is a POST request.
            context.RejectPrincipal();
        }
        else
        {
            // Something else bad happened. Don't invalidate the user's credentials unless they're actually expired, though.
            throw new Exception( "Unexpected error." );
        }
    }
    else
    {
        context.Properties.UpdateTokenValue( "access_token" , response.AccessToken  );
        context.Properties.UpdateTokenValue( "refresh_token", response.RefreshToken );

        DateTime newExpiresAt = DateTime.UtcNow + TimeSpan.FromSeconds( response.ExpiresIn );
        context.Properties.UpdateTokenValue( "expires_at", newExpiresAt.ToString( "o", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture ) );

        await context.HttpContext.SignInAsync( context.Principal, context.Properties );
    }
}
```

The problem with this code is that if the user's browser makes two simultaneous requests after their `access_token` has already expired then the user will get an error message if code later-on in the ASP.NET Core pipeline for the second simultaneous request uses the now-expired `access_token`.

...how can I get it so that the second concurrent request using an expired `access_token` will `await` the same `Task` (from `RefreshAccessTokenAsync`)?

My thought is something like this:

1. Change `_pendingRefreshes` to `ConcurrentDictionary<String,Task<String>>`.
2. Change `Boolean canRefresh = _pendingRefreshes.TryAdd( refreshToken, null );` to something like this (using a hypothetical `TryGetOrAdd` method):

   ```
   Boolean addedNewTask = _pendingRefreshes
       .TryGetOrAdd(
           key: refreshToken,
           valueFactory: rt => this.RefreshTokenAsync( context, rt ),
           value: out Task task
       );

   if( addedNewTask )
   {
       // wait for the new access_token to be saved before continuing.
       await task;
   }
   else
   {
       if( isExpired )
       {
           // If the current request's access_token is already expired and its refresh_token is currently being refrehsed, then wait for it to finish as well, then update the access_token but only for this request's lifetime (i.e. don't call `ReplacePrincipal` or `SignInAsync`.
           await task;
       }
   }
   ```

The problem is `ConcurrentDictionary<TKey,TValue>` does not have a `TryGetOrAdd` method I can use to atomically get-existing-or-add-new items.

- `AddOrUpdate` - Doesn't return any existing items. Doesn't indicate if the value returned was an existing item or not.
- `GetOrAdd` - Doesn't indicate if the value returned was an existing item or not.
- `TryAdd` - Doesn't let you atomically get any existing value with the same key.
- `TryGetValue` - Doesn't let you atomically add a new item if there isn't a value for the given key.
- `TryRemove` - Doesn't let you atomically add a new item.
- `TryUpdate` - Doesn't let you add new items.

This is fixable using a `lock` but that negates the advantages of using `ConcurrentDictionary`. Something like this:

```
Task<String> task;
Boolean addedNewTask;
lock( _pendingRefreshes )
{
    Boolean taskExists = _pendingRefreshes.TryGetValue( refreshToken, out task );
    if( taskExists )
    {
        addedNewTask = false;
    }
    else
    {
        task = RefreshAccessTokenAsync( context, refreshToken );
        if( !_pendingRefreshes.TryAdd( refreshToken, task ) )
        {
            throw new InvalidOperationException( "Could not add the Task." ); // This should never happen.
        }
        addedNewTask = true;
    }
}

if( addedNewTask || isExpired )
{
    String newAccessToken = await task;
    if( isExpired )
    {
        context.Properties.UpdateTokenValue( "access_token", newAccessToken );
    }
}
```

...or is this the correct use of `ConcurrentDictionary` for this scenario?

Comment: It seems to me that a cleaner solution is to use `GetOrAdd` and move the `isExpired` logic to a timer that *removes* the item.

Comment: I'm not sure if `Lazy<T>` helps. Something like this `ConcurrentDictionary<String, Lazy<Task<TokenResponse>>>`. With this approach, the `valueFactory` may be run more than once, but only 1 `Lazy<T>` is added => the Task is run only once when we query `Lazy<T>.Value`

Answer (score 0):

I learned [that `ConcurrentDictionary` does **not** guarantee that `valueFactory` won't be invoked exactly once per key](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31637394/is-concurrentdictionary-getoradd-guaranteed-to-invoke-valuefactorymethod-only), but may be invoked multiple times - which I can't live with because my `valueFactory` is an expensive operation with side-effects that may adversely negatively affect the user-experience (e.g. invalidating a token stored inside the user's cookies unnecessarily).

I settled on an approach using `lock` and a `Dictionary<String,Task<TokenResponse>>` instead. I do wonder how it could be improved and I'd really appreciate any feedback:

```
private static readonly Dictionary<String,Task<TokenResponse>> _currentlyRunningRefreshOperations = new Dictionary<String,Task<TokenResponse>>();

/// <summary>Returns <c>true</c> if a new Task was returned. Returns <c>false</c> if an existing Task was returned.</summary>
private Boolean GetOrCreateRefreshTokenTaskAsync( CookieValidatePrincipalContext context, String refreshToken, out Task<TokenResponse> task )
{
    lock( _currentlyRunningRefreshOperations )
    {
        if( _currentlyRunningRefreshOperations.TryGetValue( refreshToken, out task ) )
        {
            return false;
        }
        else
        {
            task = this.AttemptRefreshTokensAsync( context, refreshToken );
            _currentlyRunningRefreshOperations.Add( refreshToken, task );
            return true;
        }
    }
}

private async Task<TokenResponse> AttemptRefreshTokensAsync( CookieValidatePrincipalContext context, String refreshToken )
{
    try
    {
        TokenResponse response = await this.service.RefreshTokenAsync( refreshToken );
        if( response.IsError )
        {
            this.logger.LogWarning( "Encountered " + nameof(this.service.RefreshTokenAsync) + " error: {error}. Type: {errorType}. Description: {errorDesc}. refresh_token: {refreshToken}.", response.Error, response.ErrorType, response.ErrorDescription, refreshToken );

            return response;
        }
    }
    finally
    {
        lock( _currentlyRunningRefreshOperations )
        {
            _currentlyRunningRefreshOperations.Remove( refreshToken );
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Usually in the case where you want to ensure something is only created once, Lazy is what you're looking for. See https://stackoverflow.com/a/31637510/1756960 . Be sure to use LazyThreadSafetyMode.ExecutionAndPublication, which ensures only one thread is allowed to initialize the value.